# How to interpret coeffcient of log transformed model from mixed model on original scale in R?

Tags: r, logarithm, mixed-models, exponent

The full model for growth of plants is as follows:

```
lmer(log(growth) ~ nutrition + fertilizer + season + (1|block)
```

where nutrition(nitrogen/phosphorus), fertilizer(none/added), season(dry/wet)

The summary of the model is as follows:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 71.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.82579 -0.59620  0.04897  0.62629  1.54639 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 block     (Intercept) 0.06008  0.2451  
 Residual             0.48633  0.6974  
Number of obs: 32, groups:  tank, 16

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               3.5522     0.2684 19.6610  13.233 3.02e-11 ***
nutritionP                0.2871     0.2753 13.0000   1.043  0.31601    
fertlizeradded           -0.3513     0.2753 13.0000  -1.276  0.22436    
seasonwet                 1.0026     0.2466 15.0000   4.066  0.00101 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Plant growth here is only dependent on season, and the increase in growth is 1.0026 on the log scale. How do I interpret this on the scale of the original data, if I want to what the increase in actual plant height was? Is it only e(1.0026) ~ 3 cms, or is there any other way to interpret this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exp(1.0026)` is indeed about 3 (2.72), but this value represents *proportional* change. Growth is three times higher in the wet than in the dry season, all other things being equal.